# How can I uninstall MySQL if I have compiled it from source?

Tags: mysql, source, uninstall

I'm trying to uninstall MySQL but when I get inside the directory and type

```
make uninstall
```

It get:

> make: *** No rule to make target `uninstall'.  Stop.

I've read that I have to delete all the files that I produces when I typed

```
make install
```

But I don't quite understand where they get created. Don't they just get compiled at the same directory? And if they do, why I just can't remove that same directory?

Answer (score 0):

Is that the same source you are executing `make uninstall` where you previously did `make install` on that?. If it is the same source then `make uninstall` should just work as it is. If it is not the same source(If you took a fresh source again), then install it to the same path where you previously installed and then try to uninstall it. If you still get the same error then time to look at the `Makefile` of that source.

Comment: Yes it is. What should i be looking to at the Makefile?

Comment: looks like you don't have proper `uninstall` rule in your Makefile.